# Pass .net Form as parameter to dll

Tags: vb.net, winforms, com, vb6

This is  the vb6 dll function code which is built and added  as com reference to vb.net exe

```
 Public Function Access1(ByVal txt As String, ByRef res As Object)          
 MsgBox (TypeName(res))         
 MsgBox (res.Text)          
 End Function
```

Using below .net code  I was able to pass component as parameter to vb6 dll.

```
Dim s As New dllname.class      
s.Access1("abc", Textbox1)
```

The above code worked and msgbox display "Textbox" for typename(res).
But if I try to pass form instead of Textbox , while executing the .net code gives "`Specified cast is not valid`" error.
How to pass form object to dll function?

Comment: Upon reading your post, my initial thought was "you can't do that".  I am surprised it works for controls, and not surprised it doesn't work for forms.  After doing some research, I don't think it is possible.  One option is the [Interop Forms Toolkit](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18954/Interop-Forms-Toolkit-2-0-Tutorial) which you can [download from Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3264).

Comment: What type of "form" do you pass? Because a System.Windows.Forms.Form instance is also a System.Windows.FormsControl instance (its a derivate), and I've just tested this `dynamic i = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Project1.Class1")); i.Access1("abc", new Form { Text = "hello" });` and it works fine.

Comment: @SimonMourier i wanted to send the existing form to the dll. Using your code i could able to send the new form  to dll, but if i try to send the existing form i will get same error("specified cast is not valid").

Comment: What is the type of the "existing form" you're talking about? Object in VB Translates to an IDispatch* interface reference. If this "form" stuff is not IDispatch, you'll get that error.

Comment: @ITresearcher what are you really trying to accomplish?  Do you need the VB6 code in your DLL to access all the properties of your form?  Or just a few?  I have a potential solution for you, but it depends on what you are really trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to pass a Form back from a COM object.

In order to do this you would need to create an ActiveX containing your form and then you can embed it in your current application.

Alternatively, If you create your form in your COM component, you can show it and then return whatever values you need to your calling code.